# Locate proof of Second Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

Where can I find a **rigorous** proof of the Second Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing?

That is:

A arbitrage-free market is complete if and only if it has a unique risk neutral measure.

Please do not refer to Shreve's Stochastic Calculus For Finance II which contains a sketch of this result. Also please do not refer to the original paper.

Answer (score 2):

A proof of the statement in almost full generality can be found in Chapter 2.6 of Jarrow's [Continuous-Time Asset Pricing Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030744090) (or Chapter 2.4 if you are using the [first edition](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319778204) of this book). The rest of Chapter 2 is dedicated to the first fundamental theorem of asset pricing.

For a proof of the special case where trading at discrete times is allowed, you may see Corollary 2.2.12 in [The Mathematics of Arbitrage](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-31299-4) by Delbaen and Schachermayer. The rest of the book probably constitutes the most complete treatment of the first fundamental theorem of asset pricing.

For completeness, the original paper is: Harrison, J. Michael, and Stanley R. Pliska. "[A stochastic calculus model of continuous trading: complete markets.](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271499/1-s2.0-S0304414900X01664/1-s2.0-0304414983900388/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEEoaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCcRCud2kG%2F4kJ5idOLcZGuqzDk5bZroRjeGdv5J%2BimcwIhALY9cqWp8Qevug0hWZ3kNczwzuZdD6AWu3iWi8g4m1ZJKvoDCGMQBBoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgynPbdnFEQHXcrro7Aq1wNJyRJzrtrlf09HdcSbC8HZ07170x1KvY%2FgCAZJBDwcs6iahM%2Ba6cMP6WCqp%2F6BU9RqqtGiCqL86njeMx6QEzppny3L7OIkmm4UvhxcVOXSxIH8B8y9QT6K8jnIQ0XmD9oWwyxeSPBKFLJCQwXYxEb7fox1rnH038ChC%2BPyl3NLoMCEWguB2LfZF2D8WzvZOBYachNM7kygSJIZb9WS1eB%2BHr5b9T8jSXczeyTzQyDFfg1qGrtjCi%2FpNrExRn2xz%2FgOft4iyXMp6uy0T0zsm4m30Ly0X7FhPq5C8TtIaO94OKXD0NvZZoFivr2wbChr%2FN4PrfBSAzOW60D7SAoRvAzw%2FJf%2B5Ze5NoyGMyaGJH0%2FnOUYRdqNGYEdCFwj4WgT8%2BHpqROMqUtYtSS22s%2BzbgQsrxUvnlrqZdu9PnMkoUNM5nhEPX5UChYa8nT3NEPyYFjYzLn%2BWLeT2Fnqgh77fOi%2FJRzZaIzxpWY%2Fctw4KcKdCDiflFbotTR9VAA7dJ6fs34N5x%2F0wug%2BpthdPwe2yrolfNvE047QX7XPoTrZ0ZFvKhinWBKKAP0H%2Ft7EhUKQR%2FoJxcxh0RdID5MsqBJvrLPIa9PaPrhLS1RJqsUyQfhuejQ4hRNsqfowzu21iAY6pAG6MiD5hj033QV7JOYhEQOlK8jIbKPHb7Fmd7eiUJVLZAcHu%2B5At4wTUEgVS2hsxRk30vUDwoBYOkqjH%2Bk%2BrFfP%2BbDk76tpezZQa5zpAwko1RMc81CWhn3k5iOyrYjyrQAJ1bA9m3UE3tkEndYsSmgD4DM%2F95ZqxK6IUVcP0iTLHg5s7hyVAyrmiu3w7ZGMI8jbhwPzbnsOPAUdb4Vi3%2Bh%2F7PCq%2Bg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210806T194143Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYVTFOJ4JJ%2F20210806%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=d33de7469fb509b193db9deb452bf7df4c2f19bacb80fe6f534dbe41dbdd40e5&hash=3d339d5733ed22f805ab703c962e4b592f48e1b64025812207015c162dd72cbf&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0304414983900388&tid=spdf-a386de61-9863-439b-808e-7fd24916611f&sid=0c4de20e4cb80542504b892750888d554aaagxrqa&type=client)" Stochastic processes and their applications 15.3 (1983): 313-316. The paper is short (only 4 pages long), but it does use a lot of machinery that is left for the reader to check in the references.